# Display number in array greater than 45 only(im a complete beginner)

Tags: java, arrays

Write a program that creates an integer array of size 7 containing the following values:

```
{31, 24, 65, 41, 13, 22, 76}
```

Then, the program should display all the items in the array
greater than 45 only.

It won't display number greater than 45

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayToArrayList {
    public static void func1(int arr[]) {
        ArrayList<Integer> array_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            array_list.add(new Integer(arr[i]));
        System.out.print(array_list);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = { 31, 24, 65, 41, 13, 22, 76 };
        func1(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your comparison code ? You just getting element from array than appending it to new array?1!?!?!?!?!?

Comment: @SteveSmith your argument is perfectly valid but we have to be polite in community. it's fairly understandable that person who asked question is beginner.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty easy assignment.

```java
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int array[] = { 31, 24, 65, 41, 13,22,76 };
    Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i > 45).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

or if you don't want to use streams:

```java
for (int i : array) {
      if (i > 45) { // filter all elements lower or equal to 45
        System.out.println(i);
      }
}
```

I recommend you to study harder since this is pretty elementary.

Comment: Thank you, it works. At any point of time i wanna include an "if" statement , must i include ''for'' ?

Comment: Streams are "elementary"?  Have things really changed _that_ much since I learned programming back in the Stone Age?

Comment: @KevinAnderson i never said streams are elementary. Filtering an array of elements based on the value of an integer is.

Comment: @ErwinSmith no you can use for and if statements independent of each other. Filtering an array of elements  usually uses both.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] d = { 31, 24, 65, 41, 13,22,76 };
ArrayList<Int> resultList = Arrays.stream(d).filter(x -> x > 45).toArray();
resultList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you're just beginner, don't want to scare you with all advanced java features.

Although all the the answers are self explanatory and valid, it might take some time for a beginner as yourself to take on.

for a beginner,  **Code can be written in 1 line or in Lines that you can understand.**

You can Simple filter out values that are greater than 45

```java
public class ArrayToArrayList 
{
    public static void func1(int arr[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> array_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            array_list.add(new Integer(arr[i])); }
        for(int j=0; j<array_list.size() ; j++){
            if(array_list.indexOf(j) < 45){
                array_list.remove(j);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(array_list);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int array[] = { 31, 24, 65, 41, 13, 22, 76 };
        func1(array);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand the added value of making a new ArrayList and removing new elements afterwards. It just seems very inefficient.  Isn't it better to just only add the elements that are bigger than 45 to the array_list?

Comment: @StephanHogenboom , I completely agree with your statement and your answer, which is up voted by myself as well. But questions like this in community reminds me on my older days when I just started programming. For us as an Experienced personal it's fairly simple so write such solution in line or two, but giving answers in *their* code will make beginner's life much easier and code simpler to read. :)

Answer (score -1):

@Erwin:
I cannot see anywhere in your code comparing values of array by 45.
No need to add the values in ArrayList unless it is required otherwise.
Just sysout only those values which are grater that 45 inside for loop of Array as suggested by @Stephan